# Passing request.user in django forms error

Tags: django

I have a function that allows you to create a message and send it . I have a Usermodel called person and it has a attribute called inbox  . This attribute determines if the user would like to enable his inbox or not.

I have a form called NewMessageForm . I am trying to raise an error via form if the authenticated user has his inbox deactivated but in order to do so , I must obtain the request.user via form which is not allowing me to do so but only in views.

Can someone help me .

```
global name 'request' is not defined

File "C:\mysite\pet\forms.py" in clean_recipient
  329.             user = User.objects.get(user=request.user)

Exception Type: NameError at /create/
Exception Value: global name 'request' is not defined
```

models

```
class Person(models.Model):

inbox = (
        ('A', 'Activate'),
        ('D', 'Deactivate'),
        ('F', 'Permit To Friends Only'),
)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    inbox = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=inbox ,default='A')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Thread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recipient')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sentmessage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.body
```

forms

```
class NewMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    recipient = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=15)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,required=True,max_length=15)

    def clean_recipient(self):

            recipient = self.cleaned_data['recipient']
            user = User.objects.get(user=request.user)
            if person.inbox == D:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("You have deactivated your inbox , Please enable it at profile settings")
            if recipient:
                try:
                    recipient = User.objects.get(username=recipient)
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("This username does not exist")
                return recipient
            else:

                return recipient
```

views

```
@login_required
def Create(request):
    person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = NewMessageForm()
    if request.POST.get('_send', False):
        form = NewMessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            recipient = form.cleaned_data['recipient']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            if recipient:
                thread = Thread.objects.create(subject=subject,user=request.user)
                recipient = User.objects.get(username=recipient)
                message = Message.objects.create(user=request.user,recipient=recipient,body=message,thread=thread,sentmessage=True,read=False)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:message'))
    return render(request,'create.html',{'messages':messages,'form':form,'person':person})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could overwrite the `__init__` of your form to require a request parameter:

```
class NewMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(NewMessageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And you instantiate your form in your view like this:

```
form = NewMessageForm(request)
```

and

```
form = NewMessageForm(request, request.POST)
```

now you have `self.request` in your `NewMessageForm` instance and can use `self.request.user` from it.

Comment: thank you , may I ask why wouldn't django allow request.user in forms?

Comment: because request is only available in views by default. If you intend to use the request object not only in forms but elsewhere too, you can have a look at https://github.com/jedie/django-tools/blob/master/django_tools/middlewares/ThreadLocal.py which is a middleware that keeps the request in your thread and you can import it easily everywhere. But be careful, this approach may be seen as bad by quite some users in the Django community.